# git push a sub-directory into another main repo

Tags: git, git-push, git-subtree

I have a big main project with several directories as **subtrees**.

I want to **push** the changes in one specific subtree to its origin, which is a separate repository.

The trouble seems to be, that the current **subtree** I want to push does not originally came from the repository I want to push into. It came from a different repo, via the *subtree guides* I found by googling. It just looks very similar.

Big project layout, where `important_subtree` is the thing I am worried about.

```
~/devel/bigproject
  .git/
  some_subtree/
  other_subtree/
  important_subtree/
    abc.txt
    efg.txt   <--- new version
    hij.txt
```

And the `important_subtree` is "strongly related" to that repo:

```
~/devel/important
   .git/
    abc.txt
    efg.txt   <--- old version
    hij.txt
```

Now `~/devel/bigproject/important_subtree/efg.txt` has changed and I want to **push the important_subtree** onto the repo `~/devel/important`. So afterwards `~/devel/important/efg.txt` also has the changes.

The only thing I managed to do is to push push *everything* in *bigproject* into *important*, which is obviously not what I want. Only the changes in the subtree should be pushed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no longer so complex, you can just use the [git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) command on a clone of your repo to cull the subdirectories you don't want and then push to the new remote.

```
git clone <ORIG_REPO_DIR> <NEW_REPO_DIR>
cd <NEW_REPO_DIR>
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter <THE_SUBDIR_TO_MAKE_NEW_ROOTDIR> master
git push <MY_NEW_REMOTE_ORIGIN_URL> -f .
```

Comment: Works a charm. You should mention that `YOUR_SUBDIR` will become the root directory of the rewritten repo (which is exactly what I want). Also, I don't understand the `push`: My new remote Url? Why -f (force)? What does "." mean here? I could not recreate your push. So I went for `cd .. ; git clone <rewritten_repo> <new_directory>` -- perfect.

Comment: The push is to add the extracted files to the new remote. Is that edit more clear?

Comment: "the" new remote? I think you are saying that I can't push the rewritten repo onto the current remote, since the history is rewritten. So it's best to initialize a new repo (bare, on server, whatever) and push the rewritten to there.

Comment: I assumed you still wanted the old repo for whatever your not extracting.

Comment: I see. Nahh, in this case I can overwrite everything. I have a backup :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/) addition to git. It adds a `git subtree split` command that does what you want.

```
git subtree split --prefix=important_subtree --branch=backport <subtree merge SHA1>^.. --onto=<imported SHA1> --rejoin
git push ~/devel/important backport:master
```

This cherry-picks the changes in `bigproject` since you merged `important` as a subtree, taking only those that modified `important_subtree/`. It then applies them as new commits on top of the commit you imported from `~/devel/important` and creates a branch `backport` that you can push back in the normal way. Also `--rejoin` makes it so you don't need to use commit IDs in the future if you want to repeat the process on more changes.

There is more explanation on the [author's blog post](http://apenwarr.ca/log/?m=200904#30).

Answer (score 1):

Pushing with different branches can be a very tricky thing.

Maybe the easiest way would be:

1. Clone your "important" repo once more from the server.
2. In your "bigproject" produce patches, which contain exactly the changes you intended to
   push in the first place (e.g. git format-patch) (you might need to make "smaller" commits in a side branch first, if your original commits mix files that should be pushed and such files that shouldn't)
3. In your new clone of "important" apply the patches (git am)
4. push the new clone of "important" to its default remote master. Now the push is just a simple fast forward and should not cause trouble.

Comment: <<sigh>> thats what I thought. Thank you.